# How does the Community Bulletin get updated in private beta?

Tags: support, moderators

How are meta posts added to the Community Bulletin in private beta, when we don't have pro-tempore mods? Our Community Bulletin is quiet as compared to Buddhism.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Community Bulletin is actually automatically generated. See [this post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/224428). Basically, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions on our meta that have a reasonable number of upvotes will be automatically added to the community bulletin, as will some off-site stuff.